# NumberPicker looping when using onChange to set state within functional component

Tags: reactjs, numberpicker, react-functional-component, react-widgets

I am attempting to wrap a react-widgets NumberPicker in a functional component that updates state when `onChange` fires.

When I click on the up or down arrow of the picker, it begins to flicker as if it's in a refersh/rerender loop. I've reduced the code to the following that replicates the error for me.

I'm using React `16.13.1`, react-widgets `4.5.0`, react-widgets-simple-number `4.1.24`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NumberPicker from 'react-widgets/lib/NumberPicker';
import simpleNumberLocalizer from 'react-widgets-simple-number';

simpleNumberLocalizer();

export default function TestPicker(props) {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState(5);

  function Picker() {
    return (
      <NumberPicker value={myVar} onChange={setMyVar} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Picker />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I move the component out of the function, it works fine:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NumberPicker from 'react-widgets/lib/NumberPicker';
import simpleNumberLocalizer from 'react-widgets-simple-number';

simpleNumberLocalizer();

export default function TestPicker(props) {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState(5);

  return (
    <div>
      <NumberPicker value={myVar} onChange={setMyVar} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any ideas on why this is not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in the first snippet, the state you defined is for the parent component, and not for the child.
Whereas in the second one, the state belongs to the component itself.

If you want the first snippet to work, pass on the state to the child.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NumberPicker from 'react-widgets/lib/NumberPicker';
import simpleNumberLocalizer from 'react-widgets-simple-number';

simpleNumberLocalizer();

export default function TestPicker(props) {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState(5);

  function Picker({ value, setMyVar }) {
    return (
      <NumberPicker value={value} onChange={setMyVar} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Picker value={myVar} setMyVar={setMyVar} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've tried your changes, but still getting the same behavior.